# How can show and hide check box text with Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

[Jquery on time show and hide check box text if checked show the text if unchecked remove the text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S1aO.png)

I am Trying to show the selected check boxes text at left side,and hide it when unchecked 
this is my from code what i have tried:

```
<div class="products-row">
    <?php $tq=$conn->query("select * from os_tiffen where tiffen_status=1 order by id_tiffen ASC");
        while ($tiffen = $tq->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>  
        <div class="col-md-3"> 
            <div class="foodmenuform row text-center">
                <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $tiffen['tiffen_image'];?>" hidden>
                <label for="<?php echo $tiffen['tiffen_image'];?>"><img src="img/tiffen/<?php echo $tiffen['tiffen_image']; ?>" alt="" class="img img-responsive" /></label>
                <h3 id="tiffenname"><?php echo $tiffen['tiffen_name'];?></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }  ?>
</div>
```

And this is My Script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var FoodMenu = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
return $(this).next('h3').text();
}).get().join("<br>");
$("#selectedfood").html(FoodMenu);
});
```

And this is the place where i am showing the output:

```
<div class="related-row" id="FoodSelected">
    <h4 class="text-center">Food Selected</h4> 
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a id="selectedfood"></a></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        var output = "";
        $("input:checked").each(function() {
            output += $(this).next('span').text();
        }); 
        if (output != '')
         $(".dropdown").append('<li>'+output+'</li>');  
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-content">

  <ul class="dropdown"></ul>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox"/><span>one</span></li>  
  <li><input type="checkbox"/><span>two</span></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox"/><span>three</span></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox"/><span>four</span></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox"/><span>five</span></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox"/><span>six</span></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox"/><span>seven</span></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox"/><span>eight</span></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox"/><span>nine</span></li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

Try It Once

Comment: Its Works Fine I Can Give An Example Snippet Ok

Comment: yeah bro worked can you tell how can show them in "li" form insted of "," next line format

Comment: $(".dropdown").append('<li>'+output+'</li>');

Comment: Now Check In My Snippet I Updated It As For You Requirement.

Comment: when uncheck the value sholud disable

Comment: Sure bro i appreciate you enthusiasm

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at your layout carefully, labels don't have names inside. The possible solution is to wrap a dish name inside a container:

```
    <div class="col-md-3"> 
        <div class="foodmenuform row">
            <input type="checkbox"  id="<?php echo $lunch['id_lunch'];?>" />
            <span class="foodmenuform-name"><?php echo $lunch['lunch_name'];?></span>
            <label for="<?php echo $lunch['id_lunch'];?>"><img src="img/lunch/<?php echo $lunch['lunch_image']; ?>"/></label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and then use this container to get a dish name:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //console.log( "ready!" );
    var FoodMenu = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
        return $(this).next('.foodmenuform-name').text();
    }).get().join("</li><li>");
    $("#selectedfood").html("<ul><li>" + FoodMenu + "</li></ul>");
});
```

Comment: Wow cool it worked how can get them in `<ul><li>`   from insted of `,`

Comment: I've updated the answer, just join them by <li> tags instead and wrap the result in a missing <ul> + tags for first and last item

Comment: when uncheck the value sholud disable